# Sphinx RTD Theme and New Lines

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have written a library in python 3 and am now in the process of documenting the class, its methods, constants, etc.

I am having a subtle formatting issue with constants that are lists or dicts. My organization has taken the position that lists and dicts should be written in the following format for readability...

```
my_list = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
]

my_dict = {
    'One': 1,
    'Two': 2,
    'Three': 3,
}
```

In my class I have some constants that are lists, for example:

```
STD_LIST = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
]
```

and I've copied this list and all other class constants up into the class docstring and written a paragraph explaining each's significance. If I want the html documents to have this nice formatting I am using the vertical bar ("|") to force new lines.

Here is my restructuredText:

```
|     **STD_LIST = [**
|         **'item1',**
|         **'item2',**
|         **'item3',**
|     **]**

        This list is very important. Please do not modify it unless you know
        what you are doing. Best not to touch it ever!

        .. warning:: Don't touch :py:const:`STD_LIST` unless you know what \
        you are doing.
```

But then the following happens:[image]

The problem here is, like I said subtle, but I'm sort of a perfectionist. When a normal constant is documented the description is indented. When the vertical bars are used it disrupts this indentation. (Compare with image below)
[image: Normally how documented constants look with correct indentation]

I have found that if I remove the blank line between the constant declaration and the description this makes the description continue on the last line of the list. If I then add a vertical bar at the first line of the description it corrects this problem entirely but then causes issues with the next constant down below by not adding a blank line between them.

Does anyone know how to achieve consistency with reST and Sphinx in a case like this? I think also being able to force a newline between constants in this docstring would also be an adequate work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I got through typing my question and then had to try something that worked. I hope the solution helps other people. My answer is messy but works. If someone has a better solution, please post it!

Apparently the problem was the blank line between my declaration of the constant and my explanation for its use. Remove the blank line.

But then this was causing the first line of the description to run on the same line as the first line of the description. To solve this, add a vertical bar at the first line of the description.

BUT THEEEEEENNNNN.... This was causing the constant and the one after it to have virtually no blank space between them, which was annoying too. So I had to force a new line by adding yet another vertical bar on a line of its own on the line after the description. Here's the final solution:

```
|     **STD_LIST = [**
|         **'item1',**
|         **'item2',**
|         **'item3',**
|     **]**
|         This list is very important. Please do not modify it unless you know
          what you are doing. Best not to touch it ever!

          .. warning:: Don't touch :py:const:`STD_LIST` unless you know what \
          you are doing.
|

    **NEXT_CONST = 'Stackoverflow.com is amazing!'**
        A shoutout to the stackoverflow.com admins and users. This is a normal constant 
        string and doesn't need any vertical bar trickery to get Sphinx to format it 
        nicely.
```

The following is a nicely formatted output and exactly what I was looking for:
[image: Success!]

Exception: When the description ends with an admonition there is no need to add the vertical bar after the admonition. Instead, move the vertical bar to the line after the text description and then include a blank line before the admonition like so:

```
|     **STD_LIST = [**
|         **'item1',**
|         **'item2',**
|         **'item3',**
|     **]**
|         This list is very important. Please do not modify it unless you know
          what you are doing. Best not to touch it ever!
|

          .. warning:: Don't touch :py:const:`STD_LIST` unless you know what \
          you are doing.

    **NEXT_CONST = 'Stackoverflow.com is amazing!'**
        A shoutout to the stackoverflow.com admins and users. This is a normal constant 
        string and doesn't need any vertical bar trickery to get Sphinx to format it 
        nicely.
```

Comment: There are problems with this. (1) Difficult to maintain. (2) Lacks semantic HTML markup when rendered. (3) Lacks syntax highlighting. (4) Single quote marks are typographer quotes instead of straight quotes, which may annoy copy-pasters.

Comment: The only thing I understood was 1. Can you expand slightly on 2-4, please? I'm probably not the only one that doesn't know what you mean when you say typographer/straight quotes, for example.

Comment: (2) View and compare the rendered HTML of both examples to see the difference. Wikipedia defines [Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) as "the use of HTML markup to reinforce the semantics, or meaning, of the information in webpages and web applications rather than merely to define its presentation or look." (3) Syntax highlighting adds styles to the rendered code, applying font face, color, weight, etc. (4) Look closely at the two rendered examples. These are straight quotes: " '. These are typographer quotes “ ” ‘ ’. Python does not work well with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `code-block` and other markup.  I don't use line breaks in paragraphs of narrative documentation because it is not code. Diffing when line lengths change and are rewrapped to PEP8 compliance is painful. PEP8 is completely unnecessary for narrative documentation; keep your PEP8 in your Python code, not reStructuredText source.

```
Some introductory text about ``STD_LIST``.

    .. code-block:: python

        STD_LIST = [
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
        ]

    This list is very important. Please do not modify it unless you know what you are doing. Best not to touch it ever!

    .. warning::

        Don't touch :py:const:`STD_LIST` unless you know what you are doing.

Some introductory text about ``NEXT_CONST``.

    .. code-block:: python

        NEXT_CONST = 'Stackoverflow.com is amazing!'

    A shoutout to the stackoverflow.com admins and users. This is a normal constant string and doesn't need any vertical bar trickery to get Sphinx to format it nicely.
```

Here is the tendered reStructuredText as HTML.

[image: Rendered reStructuredText as HTML]

Comment: But having scroll-bars in StackOverflow or even in your IDE is annoying. That's why I wrapped my lines. reST doesn't complain. It may not be code but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be readable. Also, I hate my IDE throwing PEP8 line length alerts. Basically, there is no reason that I see not to manage line lengths, even for narrative text.

But thanks for the suggestion to use code blocks for the actual variable listing in the docs. This is much nicer than using vertical bars. But it does change the style significantly and idk if I want to change all the docs for other modules.

Comment: Sure, there is personal preference, and I understand your perspective. This code is reStructuredText, not Python, so PEP8 does not apply. Only Python code should comply with PEP8. I don't know of any IDE that does not allow soft-wrapping of text. PyCharm works great for this. For me the biggest reason not to use line breaks/PEP8 style is the difficulty of maintenance. When you update your PEP8-style text, you will rewrap it, and all subsequent wrapped lines in the paragraph will change versus a single word insertion. That makes ugly diffs and angers reviewers of pull requests.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my org has set a soft column limit of 80 chars and a hard limit of 120 chars and says nothing about soft-wrapping in our IDEs, even though they support it.

I really like this solution and have actually started using it, although not in the place you suggested. I like using it for examples of how methods return data, like in dictionaries. What it makes strange is how Read The Docs theme makes it look like code, naturally, but I want it to be formatted as bold text with the description non-bold. I wish there was a "block" that did this with formatted text in reST.

Comment: [Definition lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks) are a possibility, but the definition term must be on a single line, not multiple lines. The definition of the definition term must be indented. You can see an example of [rendered](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html) and [source](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.8-branch/docs/glossary.rst) documentation from Pyramid. Personally, I think it is better to just name the term, then define it, rather than try to name it and define it with multi-line markup.